# Updating google map maker opacity without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am updating the google map marker opacity as per slider(telerik control) value, but it's needs to reload the page to make marker opacity updated.
i would like to do it without reloading the page.

here is my code:

```
$("#slider").kendoSlider({
                change: sliderOnChange,
                        slide: sliderOnSlide,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 1,
                        smallStep: 0.1,
                        largeStep: 1,
                        value: 0.8
            });

function sliderOnSlide(e) {
  sliderval =e.value; 
}

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
          map: map, title: loan , position: latlngset,  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)  
        });
         marker.setOptions({'opacity': parseFloat(sliderval)})
```

many many thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `sliderOnSlide` event

```
function sliderOnSlide(e) {
  sliderval =e.value; 
  marker.setOptions({'opacity': parseFloat(sliderval)})
}
```

it will work as long as marker is in appropriate scope and it's not replaced by another instance in the meantime.